# Evaluating $\int_0^{2\pi} \ln{(a^2\sin^2(x)+b^2\cos^2{x})}dx$ with complex analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

I have been trying to compute the following integral using complex methods. I have already solved it with differentiation under the integral and obtained the following result.
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^{2\pi}\ln{(a^2\sin^2{x}+b^2\cos^2{x})}dx=4\pi \ln{\frac{a+b}{2}}$$
Where a and b are nonnegative real numbers.

This is the approach I have been trying
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^{2\pi}\ln{(a^2\sin^2{x}+b^2\cos^2{x})}dx=-4\pi \ln{2}+\int_0^{2\pi}\ln{\left((be^{iz}+be^{-iz})^2-(ae^{iz}-ae^{-iz})^2\right)}dz$$
Then use difference of squares and logarithm properties
$$I(a,b)=-4\pi \ln2 + \int_0^{2\pi}\ln{\left((b+a)e^{iz}+(b-a)e^{-iz}\right)}dz+\int_0^{2\pi}\ln{\left((b-a)e^{iz}+(b+a)e^{iz}\right)}dz$$
$$=-4\pi \ln2+2\pi\ln{(b^2-a^2)}+\sum_{p=\frac{a+b}{b-a},\frac{b-a}{a+b}}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln{(pe^{iz}+e^{-iz})}dz$$
Take the real part of both sides
$$I(a,b)=2\pi\ln{\frac{b^2-a^2}{4}}+\Re\sum_{p=\frac{a+b}{b-a},\frac{b-a}{a+b}}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(pe^{2iz}+1)dz$$
$$= 2\pi\ln{\frac{b^2-a^2}{4}}+\Re\sum_{p=\frac{a+b}{b-a},\frac{b-a}{a+b}}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(pe^{2iz}+1)dz$$
$$=2\pi\ln{\frac{b^2-a^2}{4}}+\sum_{p=\frac{b-a}{a+b},\frac{a+b}{b-a}}\int_{|z|=1}\ln{(pz^2+1)}\frac{dz}{iz}$$
When I calculate the sum of the 2 contour integrals, I get 0. All the residues are 0. The result does not match the one I got using real methods. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is problem with using residues for $\ln(z)$ function, because this function is not meromorphic. For $|p|<1$ one can use power series for $\ln(1+pz^2)$ to show that contour integral for branch, described by power series, is equal to zero. This is not the fact for $|p|\geq 1$, which is one of two cases.

Comment: Suppose $a>b$. Then the first one of $p=\frac{b-a}{a+b},\frac{a+b}{b-a}$ is inside of $|z|=$ and the other not.